# Will googlebot run my php code before index my site?

Tags: seo, indexing, hyperlink, googlebot, php-include

I'm handling my main menu links and some others important content links whith the PHP function: *include_once ('mainmenu.inc.php')*, and I'm wonder about if google will run my PHP code before determining my rank position in order to know the content and structure of my web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GoogleBot won't **run** your PHP. It's your server that will parse the PHP and feed it to the bot (just like any other regular using you website). But you may get issues if you have content being delivered by javascript or ajax.

Answer (score 0):

that's right Ashwani, Google indexes css & js files as well, I've seen websites getting backlinks from .js files